# Pandas DataFrame: Changing column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe with the column `DOB` and `ID`:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df.head() 

ID      DOB
223725  1975.0
223725  1975.0
223725  1975.0
223725  1975.0
223725  1975.0
```

There are 63 different years in `DOB`. I want to change the values in this column so that each year is replaced by a simple number. For example, the lowest value or year `1911` is changed to a value of `1`, the 2nd lowest value in `DOB` is replaced by 2, the 3rd lowest by `3` etc.

How do I make this change fast?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Series.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```
df['DOB1'] = df['DOB'].rank(method='dense')
print (df)
       ID     DOB  DOB1
0  223725  1911.0   1.0
1  223725  2000.0   3.0
2  223725  2006.0   4.0
3  223725  1985.0   2.0
4  223725  1911.0   1.0
```